# How to use Node Inspector (node-debug) with Express 4?

Tags: node.js, express, node-inspector

I am new to NodeJS and I just discovered [node inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector).

The command I usually run in order to start my application is `npm start` (I use the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/)) but when I want to debug, I need to run `node-debug` followed by a specific file.

In the official documentation of node inspector it says that in order to start the debugger I need to type :

`$ node-debug app.js`

But when I do it simply debugs the app.js file instead of running the server and starting the application.

What is the command I should run in order to debug the whole express application instead of only the app.js file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we type `npm start` the express framework looks at `package.json` file and executes the file next to the `start :` tag.

For express, this directory is `./bin/www` so the correct command is `node-debug bin/www` ran from the parent directory instead of `node-debug app.js`.

Comment: you can add any scripts you want to your package.json, maybe add a debug one to save on typing this, then you can npm run debug